# Aplay not working

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have an embedded board and have installed Ubuntu 14.04 file system on it. For some reason the audio does not play when I try to play it with '`aplay`'. I have another buildroot based file system on my MMC. On that audio plays well with the same kernel but on SD card, where I have installed the Ubuntu file system the audio does not play.

When I try to play the audio using '`aplay -vv`' I do see the bars moving on the VU-meter.

I have tried the following things with no success:

- Re-installing alsa-base and alsa-utils package
- Checking if the audio is not muted, it is not
- Comparing the amixer settings for codec and processor registers
  What could possibly be the issue? Any other places where I can check?